# RStudio MathJax error in internal browser

Tags: r, rstudio, mathjax

When trying to replicate the `MathJax` example from the `shiny`-gallery ([Here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html)), RStudio's browser does not show the proper `MathJax` but only the string (i.e., $$3^2$$ instad of the proper term). However, when I open the app in the browser, everything works fine.

Is there any known solution to this problem?

My specs:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.12.2
```

With RStudio Version 0.99.482.

Comment: what code are you typing to show the string in the viewer

Comment: For example `withMathJax(),` and then `helpText('\\(\\sqrt{2}\\) $$1-\\frac{1}{2}$$'),`

Comment: For example: the left side is the RStudio Browser, the right side is Firefox:
http://puu.sh/l3dKV/4df864ccaf.png

Comment: right but that shows up in the console. I'm asking how you get it in the viewer. the viewer is like a cheap browser but you still need to run the javascript in order for the formulas to render

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, what exactly you are asking for, however, I use exactly the same code as in the example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html

Comment: I think it's an issue with rstudio on windows, see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206616317-Shiny-mathjax-in-viewer-pane-windows).